# Thymeleaf: POST or PUT in the <form> th:action depending upon condition

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Is it possible to assign either a `POST` or `PUT` method in `from th:action` depending upon `th:if`?

Something like:

`<form th:if="${firm.firmId} == null" th:action="@{~/firms/save}" method="POST" modelAttribute="firm" th:object="${firm}">`

`<form th:if="${firm.firmId} != null" th:action="@{~/firms/save}" method="PUT" modelAttribute="firm" th:object="${firm}">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thymeleaf has conditional operator

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

You can use this operator for your purpose:

```
<form  th:action="@{~/firms/save}" th:method="${firm.firmId} != null ? PUT : POST" modelAttribute="firm" th:object="${firm}">
```

Comment: If you're using Spring this will not work properly unless you set this property in application properties: **spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true**